# Which shopping cart / ecommerce platform to choose?

Tags: web-development, magento, ecommerce, prestashop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

I need to build **an ecommerce website** within a tight budget and schedule. Of course, I have never done that before, so I have googled out what my solutions are and I have concluded that the following were not valid candidates anymore :

1. **[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/)** : Steep learning curve
2. **[osCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/)** : old, bad design, buggy and not user-friendly
3. **[Zencart](http://www.zen-cart.com/), [CRE Loaded](http://www.creloaded.com/), [CubeCart](http://www.cubecart.com/)** : based on osCommerce
4. **[Virtuemart](http://www.virtuemart.net/), [uberCart](http://www.ubercart.org/), [eCart](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/)** : based on CMS (Joomal, Drupal, WordPress) that is not necessary for my use-case

So I finally narrowed down my choices to these solutions :

1. **[PrestaShop](http://www.prestashop.com/)** : easy-to-use, great templating engine ([smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)) but [many modules are not free buy yet indispensable](http://blog.ericlamb.net/2010/05/should-we-use-prestashop/)
2. **[OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/)** : security issues and not [a great support from the main developer](http://blog.ericlamb.net/2010/05/should-we-use-opencart/). See [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?p=72582#p72582) and [here](http://blog.visionsource.org/2010/01/28/opencart-csrf-vulnerability/).

So, as you can see, I am a little bit confused and if you can **help me choosing an easy-to-use, lightweight and cheap (not-necessarily free) ecommerce solution**, I would really appreciate.

By the way, I am a Java/Grails programmer but I am also familiar with PHP and .NET. (not with Python or Ruby/Rails)

**EDIT**: It seems that this question is more appropriate for the Webmaster StackExchange site. So please **move this question to where it belongs** (I cannot do that) instead of  downvoting it. BTW, I have found out a question quite similar on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315638/php-ecommerce-system-which-one-is-easiest-to-modify) which is quite popular.

Comment: Beyond not being programming related, there really isn't an concrete answer to this.  It depends.

Comment: @Alan Of course, it depends. That's the reason I do describe my requirements in the question AND explain my left options I have. Also, tell me the difference between my question and this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81830/rails-or-grails ?

Comment: @Alan I agree, this question would be better suited for the webmasters stack exchange:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Moses OK. I was not aware of this website. Can a moderator move my question to webmasters stack exchange if you feel this is the right place?

Comment: @Alan However, I don't understand why downvoting he question...

Comment: I can't speak for all the down voters, but Stack Overflow is a programming site, and asking non-programming questions here will get you down voted.

Comment: @Alan. Ok, so why instead of downvoting, someone is not migrating this question to webmasters Q&A? I know it is possible but I cannot do that with my privileges.

Comment: @fabien7474, I agree, this downvoting business just because a question is better suited for a site X is pretty useless for everybody. Your question, as seen from a web developer perspective, was perfectly suitable for SO anyway.

Comment: These comments are irrelevant and should all be removed.

Comment: As you also knows .Net, I would also recommend considering nopCommerce which is one of the best e-commerce platform I have worked with. Its easy to scale as well. I have looked site with more than 20 millions product on nopCommerce working very nice.

Answer (score 7):

If you have never done it before and have tight schedule and budget then i'd say you are doomed anyway and have to choose whatever has the shortest learning curve for you.

Best choice out of these would be Magento but it has the longest learning curve and you'd be well comfortable with this platform after 6 months hands on working with it. I would not bother to learn the others as they are waste of time from business owners perspective. Specially viewed from support and aging technology side.

Referring to the facts **have never done it before** and **tight schedule and budget** i would suggest to rent the storefront instead (shopify, yahoo and so on, google will help you find them). That would **cut off costs for development** , **shorten the learning curve** and **you can start selling right away** and you can boost your business with reasonably priced services. If you grow and have larger budget then you should think of investing and implementing your own site.

Comment: I would second this. If you have a tight schedule and equal budget (as is the case in most of the projects we take on) it's usually more interesting to go for a hosted solution where you just focus on implementing a custom design for the client and be done with it. I've written a post comparing hosted solutions with open source, see here: http://goo.gl/KwQnK

Answer (score 3):

Try out [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/).

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience I can recommend you [Interspire Shopping Cart](https://www.interspire.com/shoppingcart/) it is not free but in my opinion quite powerful and easy to operate. They provide hosted version and server licensing.

Comment: Thx for your advice. Interspire looks very promising. I'll check it.

Answer (score 2):

I used zencart previously and just transfered to prestashop and must say it's much better, easier to use/customize

but I've not tried OpenCart so can not compare these two

Answer (score 2):

I have found Magento, difficult to learn, but worth the effort.

A great resource in understanding how magneto code works: [Designers Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide)

Awesome video tutorial series: [Building a Magento Theme Start to Finish](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.practicalecommerce.com%2Farticles%2F1540-Building-a-Magento-Theme-Start-to-Finish-Part-One-Prolegomena&rct=j&q=Building%20a%20Magento%20Theme%20Start%20to%20Finish&ei=CV9aTYkEi6S6A7XvqNIM&usg=AFQjCNEYuo30WMcP29sNI4V-UYEJwArBQQ&sig2=NQ7j8X7Otx0tz-FsfyuZvA&cad=rja)

Answer (score 2):

Magento may well be the most robust PHP shop solution, but it is big, resource hungry and not easy to implement or customize as others noted. Prestashop may not be as matured and it lacks a lot of the more advanced features, BUT it is impressively easy to learn both to the developer/webmaster and to the owner. I honestly think it will become the most popular solution in just a couple of years.

Answer (score 1):

I can say from personal experience that Prestashop is pretty good.  They used to have a problem with the upgrades being hard (1.1 -> 1.2 was so hard many people didn't do it), but since 1.3 this has not been much of an issue.  They also issue regular security updates, and have an active forum to help with problems.

My wife and her business partner are both non-technical people, and they find Prestashop easy to use, so depending on your customer that may be important as well.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate the different solutions by establishing some test products.  Then read the documentation (and test a sample installation if possible) to see how they are handled.

For example, I needed some tricky handling of [text product attributes and variable pricing](http://tutorials.zen-cart.com/index.php?article=57).  Three years ago ZenCart was the only solution that could do what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend OpenCart, since it is very useful and easy to operate, especially if you are familiar with PHP. With a great mix of recipes for both beginners and intermediates, the [OpenCart 1.4 Template Design Cookbook](http://link.packtpub.com/SQ2ZHf) is a must.

Comment: He already said OpenCart was not really an option. Cited Security Issues and Developers Negative Attitude.

Answer (score 1):

For shopping carts, I will recommend you to have a look at Magento Commerce, OsCommerce, ZenCart and Prestashop. If you are looking for something powerful, you should definitely be looking at Magento.

Clearly the Magento eCommerce with the strongest backend and securely.