# A good shopping cart

Tags: ecommerce, shopping-cart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which shopping cart / ecommerce platform to choose?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/which-shopping-cart-ecommerce-platform-to-choose)

Sorry for being so vague but I've been confused a lot in choosing a good shopping cart for my new venture. I need something which is really easy to update (like wordpress), customizable, secure, SEO friendly, not too slow, a good plugin framework so I can develop plugins if I need it.

In short, I need shopping cart as good as wordpress is for blogs. I could just download freely available ones and settle with the one I like but long-term issues aren't visible immediately.

Could you guys help me out